# python3: conditional import from one of two packages

Tags: python

I have two packages `fast` and `slow` which are "api compatible" with each other.
If `fast` is available I want to import from it, else from `slow`.
My current working solution is

```
import imp
try:
     imp.find_module('fast')
     from fast.UtilityFunctions import UtilityFunctions
     from fast.Utilities.Log import Log
     from fast.model.device_driver import DriverModel
    ...
except ImportError:
    from slow.UtilityFuntions import UtilityFunctions
    ...
# normal code
```

It there a better way to write this? Can I eliminate the copy paste job above?
i.e. what would be the pythonic equivalent of this pseudo-code?

```
import imp
try:
     imp.find_module('fast')
     alias found=fast
except ImportError
     alias found=slow
from found.UtilityFuntions import UtilityFunctions
...
```

Comment: Did you try... your pseudocode, but without the word `alias` and with the expected colon after `ImportError`?

Comment: This gives an error of
    found = fast
NameError: name 'fast' is not defined

Doing 
    import fast
    found = fast
    from found.baz import P
results in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'found'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just import the modules directly?

```py
try:
  import fast as found
except ImportError:
  import slow as found
from found.UtilityFuntions import UtilityFunctions
```

Comment: This gives an error of
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'found'

Comment: are you sure the libraries `fast` and `slow` are installed and work as you said?

Comment: yes.
the code below
```
from fast.UtilityFunctions import Q
from slow.UtilityFunctions import Q as q
p = Q()
pp = q()
print(p, q)
```
results in `<fast.UtilityFunctions.Q object at 0x7fb7e8861570> <class 'slow.UtilityFunctions.Q'>`

If I change it to
```
import fast as found
from found.UtilityFunctions import Q
...
```
I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'found'`

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
     import some_specific_module as module
except ImportError:
     import other_module
```

Try this piece of code!

Comment: This is what I am currently doing. 
The problem is I have over a dozen lines in each branch with only difference in the two branch being the root package. 
So I was looking for some method to reduce the code size.